# javascript is not decoding html values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to achieve at below

```
var a = "how are you. <br> fine";
var b = "how are you, &lt;br&gt; fine";

alert(a);
alert(b);
```

Output should be

```
How are you 
fine
```

But 
It gives me

```
how are you. <br> fine
how are you, &lt;br&gt; fine
```

&gt &lt and &nbsp are in my string

How can I decode this html in  alert message of javascript

Comment: Try jQuery UI: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#entry-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
var text = '&lt;p&gt;name&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style="font-size:xx-small;"&gt;ajde&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;em&gt;da&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;';
var decoded = $('<div/>').html(text).text();

alert(decoded);
```

**Edit:** As Rohan Kumar has suggested above, I don't think it is possible to render HTML inside an alert box (which is what you are implying in your question). but rather you would need to do something like below, i.e. use replace or **even better look into using a** [modal dialogue](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message)

```
var text = 'how are you, &lt;br&gt; fine';
var text = text.replace('&lt;br&gt;','\n');
var decoded = $('<div/>').html(text).text();
```

[Try it here - DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xebedy/Kt4vt/2/)

alert(decoded);

Comment: If your message is => I&#39;ll \&quot;walk\&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now  . then what will u do?

Comment: Can you edit as per my question. I have tryed this in alert not working.

Comment: It is showing <br> inside string it should show in new line.

Comment: @PraveenD Have a look at the edited 'Try it here - DEMO' jsfiddle link in my post. That works but it pants as you would have to replace all problem html tags with a javascript equivalent... look at using something like https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message instead - this will render most html as a web page would.

Answer (score 2):

Ty to use `\n` in place of `<br>` like,

```
var b = "how are you, \n fine";
alert(b);
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F8UCz/)

To show `HTML content` you can try [jquery-alert](http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/alert-box)

Comment: I have html encoded values in variable like &gt &lt and &nbsp

Comment: Use [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) like `alert(b.replace('&nbsp;',' '));`

Comment: your solution is specific for space and br only . but there can be any html encoded character in message. I am looking for one solution that could could decode any html decoded tag.

Comment: @PraveenD the problem with using alert is that it doesn't support HTML, only plain text.

Comment: There is no way to get proper message in alert. If not there will be big change in my project.